# Examples of closed subspaces of Baire spaces that fail to be Baire?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, baire-category

I am looking for some nice examples of [Baire spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space) containing closed subspaces that fail to be Baire.

Clearly, $X$ should not satisfy either one of the standard hypotheses for the Baire category theorem: local compactness or complete metrizability or Čech completeness because all these properties are hereditary with respect to closed subspaces.

An interesting example of a Baire metrizable space that fails to be completely metrizable is given in an answer to [What are some motivating examples of exotic metrizable spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243909). This example contains $\mathbb Q$ as a closed subspace.

It would be nice to see some further examples.

Added: I would prefer to have examples of high regularity (at least Hausdorff, preferably Tychonoff).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If I right understood the notation of the book "[Baire spaces](http://webfile.ru/6620055)" by R.C Haworth and R.A. McCoy then there is a simple example of a Baire space $\mathbb{ R^2\setminus ((R\setminus Q)\times \{0\}})$ with closed non-Baire subset $\mathbb Q\times\{0\}.$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a neat example and it's much simpler than expected! Thanks also for the reference, I didn't know about that book. Now I wish someone could come up with an example not involving $\mathbb{Q}$ (or any other dense first category subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) :-)

Comment: It seems that similarly to this example we can embed each Tychonoff space $Y$ as a closed subset into a Baire space $X$. Let $bY$ be an arbitrary compactification of $Y$. Put $X=bY\times [0;1]\setminus (bY\setminus Y)\times\{0\}$.

Comment: The link is broken, but you can find a pdf of the book here: http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.zamlynska-209257a9-0350-4a43-aa72-b08059aee740

Answer (score 6):

Consider the euclidean topology $\tau$ on the rationals and some point $x$ which is not contained in $\mathbb{Q}$. The space $Q := \mathbb{Q} \cup \{x\}$ with the topology $\tau' := \{ O \cup \{x\} : O \in \tau \} \cup \{ \emptyset \}$ is a Baire space since {x} is dense and contained in every dense subset of $Q$ - so any intersection of dense subsets of $Q$ is again dense. Furthermore $\mathbb{Q}$ is a closed subspace of $Q$ which fails to be Baire - so $(Q,\tau')$ provides an example to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot to mention explicitly that I'd prefer to have some examples with higher separation properties in order to exclude easy examples such as this one. Nevertheless, I appreciate your help and I hope its okay that I added this requirement to the question.

Comment: No problem. I would also like to see more natural examples. :)

Comment: Really nice answer. One moment is not clear to me: why any dense subset of $Q$ contains $x$?

Comment: @ZFR Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed in $Q$, no subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be dense in $Q$.